# iPhone MPMusicPlayerController playback starting position

Tags: iphone

I'm using Media Player Framework to access the user's music library on iPhone. I would like to set the playback starting position so that I can start playing a song from 30 second mark, for example.

I have trouble finding out how to do this. The MPMediaPlayerController only offers `beginSeekingForward` but that's not quite what I'm looking for as it simply accelerates the playback speed.

There is probably something really simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPMusicPlayerController's property `currentPlaybackTime` is a writeable property, so adjusting the playback starting point can be done with `player.currentPlaybackTime = 30.0`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
2009 me had some real problems. He didn't really understand properties and missed the fact that `MPMusicPlayerController.currentPlaybackTime` is writable! And he was angry. Angry because iOS3.0 had promised iPod Library "Access" and instead delivered `MPMusicPlayerController`. He had been hoping for speedy access to the music packet data upon which he would have built many fascinating and magical audio applications. Luckily, iOS4.1's `AVAssetReader` came along 1 year later and he was finally able to stop hating.

**WRONG 2009 ANSWER**

Nope, this API is deliberately crippled, which is why you don't see any functions for
 opening, or streaming from, the media file.

Your only hope is lowering the volume and calling `beginSeekingForward` until `currentPlaybackTime` returns >= 30s.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use player.currentPlaybackTime to set the time, before you start playing and playback will start at your desired point.